# Equality of Completeness property (Supremum and Infimum property) and Cauchy criterion in Real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove Completeness property and Cauchy criterion in Real numbers are equal, and I think its true. to prove this equality I think should use Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. I be so thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate? One of the standard definitions of completeness is that the Cauchy criterion holds. What's your definition of completeness?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is interesting. However, the context is missing. Can you update your question in that direction? Of what kind of spaces are you speaking? Normed spaces? Equipped with a distance? Also I have the impression that the question you're asking is a classical topology theorem. Not sure then that this forum is the right place for such questions.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  definition. Completeness Property of R Every nonempty set of real numbers that has an upper bound also has a supremum in R. so you can see  Cauchy criterion is not in  standard definitions of completeness. my source book is INTRODUCTION TO REAL ANALYSIS (Robert G. Bartle
Donald R. Sherbert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**supremum property $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy criterion**

The supremum property (which is what you call completeness) also implies the infimum property: every subset $S\subset\mathbb R$ which is bounded below has an infimum. For proof, just apply the supremum property to $-S:=\{-s~\vert~s\in S\}$. These two imply the existence of limit superior and limit inferior for all bounded sequences, since they are defined as

$$\limsup a_n:=\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}\sup_{n\geq k} a_n,\\
\liminf a_n:=\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\inf_{n\geq k} a_n,$$

both of which exist for bounded $a_n$ due to the supremum and infimum properties. If limit inferior and superior of a sequence are equal, then the sequence converges. Now the limits superior and inferior of a Cauchy sequence can't be different if they exist (I leave the proof to you). And since Cauchy sequences are bounded (again, I leave the proof to you), the limits superior and inferior do in fact exist. They are then equal, and thus the Cauchy sequence has a limit.

**Cauchy criterion $\Rightarrow$ supremum property**

Let $\emptyset\neq S\subset\mathbb R$ be a set which is bounded above. Let $b_0$ be an upper bound of $S$ and let $a_0\in S$. Now define recursively that if $\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$ is an upper bound of $S$, then $a_{n+1}:=a_n$ and $b_{n+1}:=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$, and otherwise $a_{n+1}:=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},~~b_{n+1}:=b_n$.

With these definitions, both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Cauchy sequences since $\vert a_m-a_n\vert\leq\frac{1}{2^{\vert m-n\vert}}\vert b_0-a_0\vert$, same for $\vert b_m-b_n\vert$. Because of the Cauchy criterion, both sequences converge. Even more, both converge to the same number, since the sequence $b_n-a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}(b_n-a_n)$ converges to $0$. The limit of these sequences must be an upper bound of $S$ because all the $b_n$ are upper bounds. There also can't be a lower upper bound because none of the $a_n$ are upper bounds (if $b$ is an upper bound, then all $c>b$ are upper bounds, too). So this limit is a least upper bound, in other words, a supremum.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I need equality so can you get to completeness property by assuming the cauchy criterion is correct.

Comment: @mohammadfattahian I added the other direction to my answer.